# LinkedBlockingQueue fullyLock() throw exception, fullyUnlock() won't execute

Tags: java, deadlock, reentrantlock, linkedblockingqueue

`fullyLock()` contains 2 locks：putLock and takeLock, they are all `ReentrantLock` and `NonfairSync`

```
    void fullyLock() {
        putLock.lock();
        takeLock.lock();
    }
```

Will there be such a situation :

In `remove()` method, `putLock.lock()` success, `takeLock.lock()` throw exception, then the current thread will always hold `putLock`, other thread will never be able to operate this LinkedBlockingQueue.

1. Is it possible that such a problem may occur?
2. If it is not possible, why?
3. If possible, what can jdk or us do something to remedy it?

`remove()` code:

```
        public void remove() {
            if (lastRet == null)
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            fullyLock();
            try {
                Node<E> node = lastRet;
                lastRet = null;
                for (Node<E> trail = head, p = trail.next;
                     p != null;
                     trail = p, p = p.next) {
                    if (p == node) {
                        unlink(p, trail);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                fullyUnlock();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The lock method won't throw any exceptions. Hence your issue won't occur.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html

Comment: Doesn't it throw a RunTimeException?

ReentrantLock lock() will call NonfairSync lock(), this is code:

`
        final void lock() {
            if (compareAndSetState(0, 1))
                setExclusiveOwnerThread(Thread.currentThread());
            else
                acquire(1);
        }
`

Comment: @jianjian There are no `throw` statements in that code. What are you talking about?